# how to import data from excel file into qtableview

Tags: excel, qt, csv, qtableview

i'm trying to import an excel file (that has only numbers like a matrix) into my Qtableview ! I found some code on the web that is related to QtableWidget but I ca figure it ou for QtableView
thanks in advance

Comment: I think the hardest part will be parsing the excel file format. Can you use a CSV export instead?

Comment: @SimonWarta thanks for replying ! yeah I can narrow it to csv format if it will do the job!

Answer (score 0):

Try it with QAxObject -  provides a QObject that wraps a COM objects: 
Like this:

```
  QAxObject *excel = new QAxObject ("Excel.Application", 0);
   //excel->dynamicCall ("SetVisible(bool)", true);

   QAxObject *workbooks = excel->querySubObject ("Workbooks");
   workbook = workbooks->querySubObject ("Open(const QString&)", fileName);
   QAxObject *statSheet = sheets->querySubObject ("Item(const QVariant&)", QVariant (sheetsComboBox->currentText ()));
   statSheet->dynamicCall ("Select()");


    int column = 0;
    int summe_column = 0;
    int col = 1;
    do
    {
      QAxObject* cell = statSheet->querySubObject ("Cells( int, int )", 1, col );
      QVariant value = cell->dynamicCall( "Value()" );

      QString string = statSheet->querySubObject ("Cells( int, int )", row,  column)->dynamicCall( "Value()" ).toString();


      ++col;
    }
    while (col < 40)
```

}

you need also CONFIG += qaxcontainer in your .pro file.

Comment: It should be `QT += qaxcontainer`